SupabaseUrl is required (nuxt3)
My project can't access the env variables, I have provided both the key and URL, and yet it tells me to provide them.
.env
.env (is in root directory):
SUPABASE_URL="https://ztmfoojjicbdjmqorftm.supabase.co"
SUPABASE_KEY="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Inp0bWZvb2pqaWNiZGptcW9yZnRtIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MTUzNDk0NjksImV4cCI6MjAzMDkyNTQ2OX0.9Wv9iPIxl5vI9hSDt6zX62wT1YLlS_gIF84SYXEGxts"

supabase.js
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)

export default supabase

nuxt config
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],

  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/supabase',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
  ],
  
  supabase: {
    redirect: false,
    redirectOptions: {
      login: '/login',
      callback: '/confirm',
      include: undefined,
      exclude: [],
      cookieRedirect: false,
    },
  }
})

pinia
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import supabase from "~/supabaseClient";

export const useSmoothies = defineStore ('smoothies', {
    state: () => ({
        smoothies: [],

    }),

    actions: {
        async fetchSmoothies () {
            const {data} = await supabase.from('smoothies').select()
            this.smoothies = data

        }
    }
})

home page
<template>
    <div v-for="smoothie in store.smoothies">
        {{ smoothie.title }}

    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useSmoothies } from '~/stores/smoothies';
const store = useSmoothies()

onMounted(() => {
    store.fetchSmoothies()
})
</script>

I tried to fetch Supabase using .env variables, but I can't access .env variables.
Says

provide url and key.


Try with hardcoded values first, then try to use this page to then prepend some NUXT_PUBLIC_ (if public) or NUXT_ (if private) to your env variables aka NUXT_ SUPABASE_KEY or similar.
